# How can I get document field with jqCouch?

Tags: couchdb

Has anyone ever used jqCouch - jquery plugin for CouchDB? 
Know how to retrieve the fields in a document?

with futon i created a document ex:

```
_id "ceb5da7e0ac10c619e81b2a9c2ab115e"
_rev "2-9ae589297cf186b6899f5762a40324e5"
post "great"
```

I try this for example:

```
var dc = $.jqCouch.connection('doc');
var all = dc.all('testapp');
var all_documents = null;
if (all.total_rows > 0) {
  all_documents = all.rows;    
}

var c = all_documents[0].value.post;
```

into value I have only `_id` and `_rev`, but not post.
thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Are you sure you hit "save" in futon when you edited the document?